# Printing over 50 emoji's in one line forces unwanted whitespace (Python) (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently working on making a python boardgame representation in the terminal using emoji's, but as soon as my emoji print gets past 50 emoji's, it forces whitespace. This does not happen when printing a string of 50 normal characters or a string of equally lengthed characters. When I do even more emoji's, things sometimes get even weirder with question mark emoji's (see
[Terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMDUo.png)).

```
s = "\U0001F7E8"
print("50:")
print(s*50)
print("\n51:")
print(s*51)
print("\n60:")
print(s*60)
print("\n70:")
print(s*70)
print("\n80:")
print(s*80)
print("\n220:")
print(s*220)    

print("what I'm currently working on")
#I made string_representation with a lot of code above which I don't feel like matters for my question, so I left that out.
print(string_representation)
print("sadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfdssadsfdgfhgjgfds")
```

Comment: I tried with different terminals but I dot get any line break, I'm unable to get the emoji character (I get a box with cross). How do you get this `2: Python` terminal?

Comment: `2: Python` is just a second python terminal, that shouldn't make a difference I think. For getting the emoji, have you tried either putting the actual emoji inside the ' ' or using the unicode?

Comment: I tried the green top right button (never used before) and that gave me a `2: Python` terminal. I always use F5 and select the correct config, if I use Steves snake emoji I see the emoji. I still don't see you problem effect, I see 2 question marks with the 220 case

Comment: Hmm, it's weird that you can't see the emoji, can you send a screenshot of your code/terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried locally, it's the problem with the python multiple print(*) and the emoji you take('\U0001F7E8'). You'd better switch to some other emojis.

```
# s = '\U0001F7E8'
s = ''
# s = ''
s5 = s*5

print(s*60)

for i in range(60):
    print(s, end="")
print()

for x in range(6):
    print(s*10, end="")
print()

print(s5*12)
print()

for i in range(12):
    print(s5, end="")
print()

for x in range(4):
    print(s5*3, end="")
print()
```

Comment: Wow, it seems to just be the case for the exact emojis that I want to use... I've been testing with others from https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html but it only happened with the coloured squares/circles I need. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Do you still take advantage of '\U0001F7E8'?

Comment: The problem occurs using the unicode and using the actual emoji.

Comment: I don't. Right now im using different emoji's that do sort of work (still getting buggy questionmarks though). But it does look a lot uglier with them than with the emoji's I wanted.

Comment: uglier, haha. Although I haven't helped you solved the problem. But if this answer offers some help to you, can you accept it or upvote it? thanks a lot, and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print them in one print condition like this

```
print("50:", s*50, "\n51", s*51, "\n51")
```

and so on maybe thats your problem

because in the string representation you added them in one print condition

Comment: Tried it. Still the same problem